Merge several rasters into one large raster file in R with 'terra'
I have several rasters (.tif) files and want to merge them into a final large raster. Each smaller raster file is also in relatively large size.
I used the terra R package's vrt function to first build a .vrt file, and then used writeRaster to write the final large raster into the directory. However, my R session aborted when it started the writeRaster process.
I tried with two different codes, but both of them made the R abort.
The first code:
library(terra)
test1 <- rast('I:/DATA/output/MI_01.tif')
test2 <- rast('I:/DATA/output/MI_02.tif')
test3 <- rast('I:/DATA/output/MI_03.tif')
v <- vrt(c("I:/DATA/output/MI_01.tif", 
           "I:/DATA/output/MI_02.tif",
           "I:/DATA/output/MI_03.tif"),
         "test.vrt", overwrite=T)
plot(v)
writeRaster(v, "I:/DATA/output/MI_Merged.tif")

The second code:
library(terra)
t.lst <- list.files("/lustre1/scratch/output/MI_tile/", pattern=".tif", full.names=TRUE)
MIs <- function(t.lst, fout="") {
  r <- vrt(t.lst)
  if (fout != "") {
    writeRaster(r, fout, overwrite=TRUE)
    fout
  } else {
    wrap(r)
  }
} 

MIs(t.lst, fout = "/lustre1/scratch/output/MI_final/MI_merge.tif")

The information about my rasters for merging:
> test1
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 120000, 132818, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2636075, 5956525, 1385925, 4385925  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : MI_01.tif 
name        : spat_o6xCi6omAQKQWfp_896553 
min value   :                           0 
max value   :                           1 
> test2
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 41203, 132818, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2636075, 5956525, 4385925, 5416000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : MI_02.tif 
name        : spat_Qs2AebAaSIInfQI_2501483 
min value   :                            0 
max value   :                            1 
> test3
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 161203, 132818, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 25, 25  (x, y)
extent      : 2636075, 5956525, 1385925, 5416000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source      : MI_03.tif 
name        : spat_U51IfANH30JHuwp_503810 
min value   :                           0 
max value   :                           1 

I am using HPC (supercomputer) to run my job, so the RAM I can use is up to around 750 GiB. I am wondering how much memory I will need to merge these rasters. I think at the end the final raster will be around 5 GB, so I assumed the RAM won't be the problem.
From HPC, I got the output file with error:
terra 1.7.55
|---------|---------|---------|---------|
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x152a3df7ed20, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: 0x2ee8190>,     dll = list(name = "Rcpp", path = "/x/miniconda3-new/envs/R_new/lib/R/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so",         dynamicLookup = TRUE, handle = <pointer: 0x43328d0>,         info = <pointer: 0x38933d0>), numParameters = -1L), <pointer: 0x7299890>,     <pointer: 0x3038160>, .pointer, ...)
 2: x@cpp$writeRaster(opt)
 3: .local(x, filename, ...)
 4: writeRaster(r, fout, overwrite = TRUE)
 5: writeRaster(r, fout, overwrite = TRUE)
 6: MIs(t.lst, fout = "/lustre1/scratch/output/MI_final/MI_final.tif")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
/var/spool/slurmd/job61846166/slurm_script: line 19: 1794009 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) Rscript BuildVRTmap.R

And I think this error refers to the memory usage of my R scripts.
So my specific questions here would be:

How could I merge all these rasters to build a large raster in R to avoid the R being aborted and with lower memory required?
How to estimate the memory I will need when using vrt function to build and write a large raster?


I would start by updating my terra version. Just trying to test some conditions by creating test_1 from a matrix : cannot allocate vector of size 118.8 Gb, so I'll reduce by factor of 1000 (dim(tst1)) 120, 132, 1. tst2: 40Gb,  tst3: 159.5 Gb, so 318.3 Gb before a copy is made. see also ?terra::mem_info. Given my tech, I play in the baby raster end of the pool. You do arrive at writing test_2, it appears above, prior to blowing through pre-allocated memory. You might want to consider 'makeTiles' of your files on disk prior to further processing.

The error is a segmentation fault, usually the code trying to access memory that is not available to it. That does not necessarily mean the system is out of memory, but more likely some buffer that is full (which itself could be a memory allocation problem). Probably better to post this on the GitHub page: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues

@Chris Thanks for your replies. I tried to use makeTiles function to split my rasters into even smaller tiles and do the vrt again, but the same problem still occurred...

@Patrick I also tried using the gdalbuildvrt module directly in HPC and with 216 memory reserved for this HPC job, it works, but the output 'MI_merge.tif" file became 33 GB, which is way larger than it should be since the input 'test1', 'test02', 'test03' data in total are around 5 GB.

This looks more-and-more like a library problem, not something to do with your code or your data. Since .tiff is an "easy" format (well described, not too many complications, stable libraries that have been in use for 20+ years), I'd start looking for an issue in the vrt part. But again, not something that can be solved in this forum.

@Patrick Thanks for the quick response! I will post this problem as an issue on the terra GitHub page!
